# What is the Python convention **kwargs vs **kwds vs **kw?

Tags: python, keyword-argument

Is there a python naming convention for **key word arguments**?

Comment: Usually **kwargs, sometimes **kw. I've never seen **kwds

Comment: @gnibbler here's an example where Guido uses **kwds http://code.google.com/p/appengine-ndb-experiment/source/browse/ndb/model.py

Comment: well now I *have* seen it. I still think that is the most unconventional of the 3, but you know, there is some Python code I haven't seen yet :)

Comment: Here's another example of `**kwds`  : http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.pairwise_distances.html#sklearn.metrics.pairwise.pairwise_distances

Comment: And mode `**kwds`: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html . Looks like `kwds` is trendy :-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Nope, but normally it is named as `**kwargs`, but you can name it anything you want. Only thing is it should come at the last following any position args and named args.

Answer (score 11):

The most popular convention is `**kwargs`, as seen in documentation and PEPs.

Comment: There are exceptions, e.g.: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484 uses `**kwds` instead of `**kwargs`.

Comment: There are more exceptions: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html

Answer (score 10):

The key is consistency. In your personal code and in the project on which you're working. If I'm reading your code and see you using `**kwarguments` in all functions, I can calibrate myself to read it fine. If you use `**k` in one place and `**kargs` in another, that's a different story.

As for conventions in Python code generally, my experience is the same as Senthil's - `**kwargs`.